# Fresco image not visible in Recyler View on Android Jellybean devices

Tags: android, fresco

While loading image a thin line appears and the image is not visible while using fresco in a RecyclerView on Android Jellybean devices but the same works on KitKat+ devices.

> Samsung - 4.1.1 - API 16 - 768 X 1280

[image: Loading Image Using Fresco]

> SamsungGalaxyNote2 - 4.3 - API 18 - 720 X 1280

[image]

> NOTE : Have tested in multiple devices and the scenario is the same

This is the way we are using it in the library

```
            if (newsModelStoreList.get(position-1).getImageUrl() != null) {
            String imageUrl = newsModelStoreList.get(position-1).getImageUrl();
            String extension=".jpg";
            try {
                extension = imageUrl.substring(imageUrl.lastIndexOf("."));
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

            }

            Log.d("extension: ",extension);
            if(extension.equals(".gif")) {
                Log.d("Detected Gif: ", "Starting gif controller");
                DraweeController controller = Fresco.newDraweeControllerBuilder()
                        .setUri(Uri.parse(imageUrl))
                        .setAutoPlayAnimations(true)
                .build();
                myHolder.newsImage.setController(controller);

            }
            else
            {
                myHolder.newsImage.setImageURI(Uri.parse(imageUrl));
            }

        }
```

> I AM 100% SURE THAT URL IS AVAILABLE AND IS WORKING ON 4.4+ DEVICES

This is the news_layout.xml which gets inflated

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/feed_bg"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_parent_rounded_corner"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/feed_item_margin"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/feed_item_padding_top_bottom"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/feed_item_padding_top_bottom" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/timestamp"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="posted 5 min ago"
                android:textColor="@color/timestamp"
                android:textSize="@dimen/feed_item_timestamp" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/newsTitle"
            android:textSize="22dp"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/feed_item_status_pad_left_right"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/feed_item_status_pad_left_right"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textColorLink="@color/com_facebook_blue"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            />

       <TextView
            android:id="@+id/newsInformation"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"

            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textColorLink="@color/com_facebook_blue"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/feed_item_status_pad_left_right"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/feed_item_status_pad_left_right"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/feed_item_status_pad_top" >


           </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/viewMore" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        </LinearLayout>
```

> SimpleDraweeView is used here ...

```
        <com.facebook.drawee.view.SimpleDraweeView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:id="@+id/newsImage"/>
```

> The rest of the xml is just for reference just in case it would help

```
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/pad_5dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/awesomeness"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/timestamp"
                android:text="Awesomeness: "
                android:textSize="@dimen/feed_item_timestamp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/awesomenessCountNumber"
                android:text="0"
                android:textColor="@color/timestamp"
                android:textSize="@dimen/feed_item_timestamp"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/pad_5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/pad_5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/pad_5dp">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:id="@+id/awesomeButton"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:background="@drawable/awesome_button_2"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:id="@+id/facebookSharePost"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:background="@drawable/facebook_icon"
                />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:id="@+id/whatsApp"
                android:background="@drawable/whats_app_icon"/>

            <View
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                />

            <TextView
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Report"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:id="@+id/report"
                android:background="@drawable/report_empty" />


        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can we see a code snippet?

Comment: @tyronen have added the code snipper sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guesses as to what you are doing wrong:

- You are using `wrap_content.` Fresco does not support this unless you also supply a `fresco:viewAspectRatio.` See the [guide to Drawees](http://frescolib.org/docs/using-drawees-xml.html) and the [longer explanation](http://frescolib.org/docs/wrap-content.html) about wrap_content.
- You are using `android:scaleType`. This has no effect on SimpleDraweeViews. You need to use `fresco:actualImageScaleType`. Also be sure that `fitXY` is really what you want; this does not preserve the aspect ratio. See the documentation on [scale types](http://frescolib.org/docs/scaling.html).

Comment: 1. Sir What should be the width of image for the news feed where image lengths wary ??? (IMP*) 

2. It worked if I give a fixed size. Why does it work in android 4.4+ devices and not on the others ????

Comment: Using focus crop with aspect ratio solves my problem to a certain extent.
But still the top portion of the image gets cut. What to do ??

Image Link : http://postimg.org/image/f18vz4g97/

Comment: If you never want the image cropped, don't use focusCrop. Use fitCenter.